# Привязка ComboBox к списку WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

Пользователем в окне создаётся заданное кол-во ComboBox.

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>

    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ListComboBoxSource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

К примеру создаётся 5 ComboBox и пользователь выбирает в каждом разные (значения) элементы.

Если я привязываю SelectedItem к свойству типа String, привязка осуществляется, но все ComboBox имеют одно и тоже значение SelectedItem (дублируют друг друга).
Если пытаюсь связать SelectedItem со списком, ничего не происходит.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> listComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> ListComboBoxItems
{
    get { return listComboBoxItems; }
    set { listComboBoxItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Вопрос, как получить выбранные элементы пользователем из всех ComboBox в список?

Comment: Вы все ComboBox привязываете к одному и тому же свойству, естественно значение будет везде одинаковое. Заведите 5 свойств `SelectedItem`, а потом уже из них формируйте список

Comment: Не о том. Нужен список, где каждым элементом является SelectedIndex или SelectedItem. Если есть 15 ComboBox, то в списке тоже должно быть 15 элементов с данными.

Comment: можно узнать что вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать написав простую обертку:

```
class Item : Vm
{
    string v;
    public string Value
    {
        get => v;
        set => Set(ref v, value);
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Items,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                              AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

В главной VM у вас должен быть список возможных значений:

```
public List<string> Items { get; } = new List<string>
{
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 6",
    "Item 7",
    "Item 8",
    "Item 9"
};
```

и список оберток, в которые вы будете сохранять выбранные элементы:

```
public List<Item> SelectedItems { get; }
    = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => new Item()).ToList();
```

Обратите внимание, вы должны этот список заранее инициализировать нужным количеством пустых оберток. В данном примере создается 3 оболочки, поэтому будет 3 комбобокса:

[image: скрин]

Затем получить все выбранные элементы можно с помощью простой Linq-конструкции:

```
SelectedItems.Select(x => x.Value)
```

Ну и вместо элементов типа `string` вы можете использовать элементы любого типа, для этого нужно изменить тип элементов коллекции `Items` и тип свойства `Item.Value` (`Item` можно вообще сделать дженериком)

---

"Загнать" эти ComboBox'ы в заголовки DataGrid можно только в code behind, так как `ComboBox.Columns` - это обычная коллекция, а не `ItemsControl`:

```
var vm = (MainVm)DataContext;
foreach (var item in vm.SelectedItems)
{
    var cb = new ComboBox { ItemsSource = vm.Items, DataContext = item };
    var b = new Binding(nameof(Item<string>.Value));
    cb.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, b);
    MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = cb });
}
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Почему то выдаёт ошибку


`get => v;
set => Set(ref v, value);`


1. В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создания нового объекта. 


2. "Item.Value.get": не все ветви кода возвращают значение.

Comment: Какая студия стоит?

Comment: VS Community 2015

Comment: Перепишите так: `public string Value
    {
        get { return v; }
        set { Set(ref v, value); }
    }`

Comment: Базовый класс для VM возьмите здесь: https://pastebin.com/JriyzCEh

Comment: Добавил больше кода. DataTemplate находится в заголовке столбца DataGrid. Не получается использовать ItemsSource.

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, чтобы в каждой строчке DataGrid был ComboBox или что? @Артём

Comment: В заголовке каждой колонки есть (вместо заголовка столбца) ComboBox. Пользователь вводит свои данные в таблицу и выбирает из ComboBox значение столбца. Но не получается получить выбранные значения пользователем.

Comment: @Артём, а зачем ComboBox в заголовке? почему не в ячейке?

Comment: Я не рассматривал такой вариант. Вы имеете в виду, ComboBox`ы в первой строке?

Comment: @Артём, вы говорите, что пользователь вводит данные в таблицу, в какую? В этот DataGrid? Почему просто не сделать ComboBox в нужной ячейке, зачем пихать его в заголовок?

Comment: DataTable привязан к DataGrid. Что бы пользователь обозначил тип данных в каждой колонке.

Comment: @Артём, я думаю ничего не получится, выглядит очень костыльно. Предлагаю вам вынести настройки типов для колонок отдельно, просто как в этом ответе, а потом уже создавать вашу DataTable

Comment: @Артём, добавил в ответ как вы можете это сделать, но я не думаю, что это хорошее решение, лучше сделать как я предлагаю в предыдущем комментарии

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.